# how to use array_push when pushing both key and value in PHP

Tags: php

I have an empty array. I am able to push values using

```
array_push($list, item[0]);
```

But how do I push both key and value.

```
array_push($list[$key], $item[0])
```

this does not work.

Answer (score 4):

```
$list['key']=$item[0];
```

should work.

> Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the key => value pairs you could use array_merge function.

```
$arr1 = array('apple' => 'fruit', 'banana' => 'fruit');
$arr2 = array('turnip' => 'vegetable', 'mushroom' => 'other');

$newArray = array_merge($arr1,$arr2)
```

This will return:

```
Array
(
    [apple] => fruit
    [banana] => fruit
    [turnip] => vegetable
    [mushroom] => other
)
```

But if two keys are the same in two arrays the one in the first array will be overwritten by the value in the second.